# Odd behavior of a c program with fork()

Tags: c, fork

In my homework I should explain what is happening in the following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int x = 1; 
    if(fork() == 0){// child
        printf("printf1: x=%d\n", ++x);// add then print
    }
    printf("printf2: x=%d\n", --x);
    exit(0);  
}
```

It's pretty straightforward and easy to understand. Most of the time I get the following output:

```
printf2: x=0
printf1: x=2
printf2: x=1
```

This means that the parent process was completed before the child and the child became a zombie process.
But sometimes I get the following output:

```
printf1: x=2
printf2: x=1
```

After printing that the program freezes (It does not print anything and does not stop). 
I am running the program on Ubuntu. 
Any explanation will be appreciated.

Comment: after the program 'freezes' what happens if you push the 'enter' button? Are you getting the prompt or not?

Comment: Are you running that program from a shell or an IDE?

Comment: @Serge Yes, I am getting the prompt after pressing enter.

Comment: @rici I am running the program form a shell.

Comment: It appears that the child process prints its output after the prompt is displayed. I didn't notice that.

Comment: Your main process finishes before the child. Shell prints the prompt and the child overwrites it on the terminal. It is not hanging, just the prompt gets overwritten. This would not happen if you wait for the child process to finish. It also overwrites the output of the main process because you have neither sync nor atomic writes to the terminal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 3 processes writing to your terminal: parent, child and the shell interpreter. The parent process and the shell have "syncronized" output, but the child process may interleave its output with either of those. What you may perceive as a hanged process, may actually only be mangled output.

When you think it has hanged, you may try to enter a command and press enter...

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean with the synchronized output.  Child and parent processes prints normally on the terminal even when they are working simultaneously. I don't understand why the output is mangled.

Comment: @Nour0700 Think about what happens if the parent process finishes before the child process. Then the parent process exits, and the shell takes over and print its prompt. Then the child process prints its output and exits. But there's no "synchronization" between the child process and the shell, so no new prompt will be printed. That could make it seem like the program just hangs. You need to look at the *full* output in the window. And press the `Enter` key in the shell to get a new prompt.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Now I understand. It's not hanging it just printing the output after the prompt. Thank you.